# How to write a PHP code on simple math expression?

Tags: php

I am a newbie of PHP coding, and want to do a simple math example, **d=(a+b)/c**.

The values of **a** and **b** will be submitted by the user from a webpage containing PHP form.
The value of **c** is predefined in the PHP page.

When the user click "submit" in this webpage. 
I expect to get the result of **d** in the bottom of the same webpage.

Any example code will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to to with MySQL or CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="c" name="c" value="10" />
<label for="a">a: </label>
<input type="text" id="a" name="a" /> <br />
<label for="b">b: </label>
<input type="text" id="b" name="b" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<br />

<?php
if (isset($_POST["a"]) && isset($_POST["b"]) && isset($_POST["c"])) {
    if (is_numeric($_POST["a"]) && is_numeric($_POST["b"]) && is_numeric($_POST["c"])) {
        $d = ($_POST["a"] + $_POST["b"])/$_POST["c"];
        echo "d = ". $d;
    } else {
        echo "all values must be numeric!"
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

It is not that different from other languages. Assuming you are using POST to submit the form.

```
$d = ($_POST['a'] + $_POST['b'])/$c;
```

<sub>***WARNING:*** Injection Vulnerability if used in SQL query. But shouldn't be a problem while learning.</sub>

To display the result. Use `echo` statement, which prints out the text/variable to the browser.

```
<?PHP echo $d; ?>
```

Place this snippet, where you want to display.

For example:

```
<div> Here is the result: <?PHP echo $d; ?> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
    My Math Page
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post">
    <label>Enter a:<input name="a" type="text"<?php if(isset($_POST['a'])) echo "value='".$_POST['a']."'"; ?>/></label><br>
    <label>Enter b:<input name="b" type="text"<?php if(isset($_POST['b'])) echo "value='".$_POST['b']."'"; ?>/></label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
</form>
    <div>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_POST["a"],$_POST["b"]))
        echo "some fields are missing";
    if(is_numeric($_POST['a'])&& is_numeric($_POST['b']))
        echo "d=". ($_POST['a'] + $_POST['b'])/$c;
    else echo "You must enter only numbers";
    ?>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: there was some flaw in the code. I have updated it. Now try it.